# excel dropdown with address as result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A normal data validation dropdown in Excel results in the selected *value* being put into the cell. In my case though, I am referencing another list in my sheet whose elements can change. My goal is to make those changes apply to already selected dropdown items.

Example:
Referenced list in dropdown (sheet "List"):

- A
- B
- C

User selects A from the dropdown in sheet "Selection":

- A

Now the user changes A to Y in sheet "List":

- Y
- B
- C

The user's selection in sheet "Selection" still shows A, but it should now show Y:

- A

Is this possible in any way? Can I e.g. make the dropdown result in an address to the value, instead of the value itself?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the user change the value in sheet "List"? Manually (writes in the formula bar)?

Comment: Yeah, the list in "List" are just plain text values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There unfortunately isn't any way to do this with a formula or build-in function (that I'm aware of)

Here is something simple you could apply and work with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target(1, 1), Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Selection").Range("A1").Value = Target(1, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Assuming `Range("A1:A3")` is the list you are refering to. Paste this under your List sheet.

Answer (score 1):

## Drop Down feat. Worksheet Change Event

- To 'copy' your setup, in worksheet `List` I have created a name
  `Drop1` which refers to the column range containing the values. Then
  I have created a Validation Drop Down in `B2` in worksheet
  `Selection` and chose the name (`Drop1`) as the list.
- Change the constants (Const) to fit your needs.

**Module1**

```vb
Option Explicit

Public strListSheet As String
Public strListRange As String
Public vntList As Variant

Sub Drop(rngList As Range)

    Const cDropSheet As String = "Selection"
    Const cDropRange As String = "B2"

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim vntNew As Variant
    Dim vntVal As Variant
    Dim Nor As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cDropSheet).Range(cDropRange)
    vntVal = rng
    vntNew = rngList
    Nor = UBound(vntList)

    For i = 1 To Nor
        If vntList(i, 1) = vntVal Then
            If vntVal <> vntNew(i, 1) Then
                rng = vntNew(i, 1)
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    vntList = vntNew

End Sub

Sub Initialize()

    Const strDrop as string = "Drop1"

    Dim str1 As String
    Dim lngInStr As Long

    ' Prepare
    str1 = Names(strDrop).RefersTo
    lngInStr = InStr(1, str1, "!")

    ' Write Public Variables
    strListRange = Right(str1, Len(str1) - lngInStr)
    strListSheet = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(WorksheetFunction _
            .Substitute(Left(str1, lngInStr - 1), "=", ""), "'", "")
    vntList = Worksheets(strListSheet).Range(strListRange)

End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Initialize
End Sub
```

**List** (Worksheet)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ErrInit
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Dim rngList As Range
        Set rngList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strListSheet) _
                .Range(strListRange)
        If Not Intersect(Target, rngList) Is Nothing Then
            Drop rngList
        End If
    End If
Exit Sub

ErrInit:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred. Error '" & Err.Number & "':" _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Initialize

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this VB approach. Indeed, that would work. I will wait with accepting it as answer tho, because I'm still hoping to see an answer without script (i.e. just formulas). If there e.g. was a way to have the dropdown fill in addresses instead of values, the problem would be solved.